# MYSQL Select all where value is highest

Tags: mysql

In a MYSQL query, how can i select all of the rows where a value is highest for example:

```
SELECT      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_date) AS `date`,
            release_version
FROM        content
WHERE       id = '1' 
ORDER BY    `date` DESC
```

This will output for example:

[image: output]

Note: the amount of rows with the same/different `release_version` is variable and therefore i can't use LIMIT.

i only want to select those where the `release_version` is highest (3 in this case)

How can i do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be simply as

```
SELECT * 
FROM   content
WHERE  release_version = (SELECT MAX(release_version) FROM content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HAVING clausule.

```
SELECT      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_date) AS `date`,
        MAX(`release_version`) as max,
FROM        content
WHERE       id = '1' 
HAVING max > 3
ORDER BY    `date` DESC
```

**EDIT**

OR you can use

```
SELECT      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_date) AS `date`,
       `release_version` as max,
FROM        content
WHERE       id = '1' AND release_version = (SELECT MAX(`release_version`) FROM content WHERE id = '1')
ORDER BY    `date` DESC
```